# Why do identical objects get different printed outputs in IntelliJ Scala REPL depending on how they were created?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

This is something interesting I noticed today while playing around with the Scala REPL in IntelliJ.

Given these two lines:

```
val myVector = Vector.tabulate(10)((x: Int) => x + 1)
val myVector2 = (1 to 10).toVector
```

The REPL prints:

```
myVector: scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
myVector2: Vector[Int] = Vector(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

Why does the first show the whole path (scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int]), while the second is only Vector[Int]?

To cover all the bases I've confirmed that they are indeed the same class:

```
myVector: Class[?0] = class scala.collection.immutable.Vector
myVector2: Class[?0] = class scala.collection.immutable.Vector
```

This is more of a curiosity than anything but it could be confusing for beginners who are most likely to use the REPL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get verbose type info:

```
$ scalam 
Welcome to Scala 2.12.0-M5 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_92).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> :type -v Vector.tabulate(10)((x: Int) => x + 1)
// Type signature
scala.collection.immutable.Vector[Int]

// Internal Type structure
TypeRef(
  TypeSymbol(
    final class Vector[+A] extends AbstractSeq[A] with IndexedSeq[A] with GenericTraversableTemplate[A,scala.collection.immutable.Vector] with IndexedSeqLike[A,scala.collection.immutable.Vector[A]] with VectorPointer[A @scala.annotation.unchecked.uncheckedVariance] with Serializable with CustomParallelizable[A,scala.collection.parallel.immutable.ParVector[A]]

  )
  args = List(
    TypeRef(TypeSymbol(final abstract class Int extends AnyVal))
  )
)

scala> :type -v (1 to 10).toVector
// Type signature
Vector[Int]

// Internal Type structure
AliasTypeRef(
  Alias(type Vector[+A] = scala.collection.immutable.Vector[A])
  args = List(
    TypeRef(TypeSymbol(final abstract class Int extends AnyVal))
  )
  normalize = TypeRef(
    TypeSymbol(
      final class Vector[+A] extends AbstractSeq[A] with IndexedSeq[A] with GenericTraversableTemplate[A,scala.collection.immutable.Vector] with IndexedSeqLike[A,scala.collection.immutable.Vector[A]] with VectorPointer[A @scala.annotation.unchecked.uncheckedVariance] with Serializable with CustomParallelizable[A,scala.collection.parallel.immutable.ParVector[A]]

    )
    args = List(
      TypeRef(TypeSymbol(final abstract class Int extends AnyVal))
    )
  )
)
```

You might say, as I did, "Wha?"

In `TraversableOnce.toVector` has type `scala.Vector`:

```
 def toVector: Vector[A] = to[Vector]
```

The `tabulate` factory method is on `GenTraversableFactory` so I won't go there. But apparently the return type, which might be a type arg, shakes out as the unaliased Vector.

Should add that they're looking at custom printing of values and also of types. And there's a [comment on the :type command](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.0-M5/src/repl/scala/tools/nsc/interpreter/package.scala#L178) to add an option to normalize types to avoid this issue.

Also, here's a good one:

```
scala> Vector
res0: collection.immutable.Vector.type = scala.collection.immutable.Vector$@5ffd35dd
```

Comment: This is an excellent answer @som-snytt. Thank you, I learned something new today.